# Android deep link opens the app only if link was added in Open by default

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link, deferred-deep-linking

The title basically says it all, but maybe I can go into more details. Just running the app for the first time and trying to open it with a set deep link doesn't work. The link is opened in a browser. But if I go into the app's setting/Open by default and add the link manually, clicking on a deep link now opens my app.
I've only tested this with a debug version of the app. Could this be an issue?

My intent filter in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="${deepLinkHost}"
        android:pathPrefix="/deeplink/"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: For autoverification your app has to be signed with the sha key provided in your asset-links.json file. Therefore, you must run it in the correctly signed release mode to test it. I think it is not possible to test it in debug mode. More information here https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#sign-the-app

Answer (score 0):

You must split your

```
<data
    android:host="${deepLinkHost}"
    android:pathPrefix="/deeplink/"
    android:scheme="https" />
```

to

```
<data android:host="${deepLinkHost}" />
<data android:pathPrefix="/deeplink/" />
<data android:scheme="https" />
```

and add

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).